# quick file upload java rest api mimepull close issue with multi part form data

Tags: maven, file-upload, jersey, multipartform-data, dependency-management

Can anyone help me with this **mimepull** library issue please?

i think the problem is about deprecated method in newer version of the library or mismatch of dependency versions. Or someone from the jersey team pushed some untested code to production.

my problem is similar to the one at 
[org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEMessage.close()V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46837956/org-glassfish-jersey-server-containerexception-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org)

i have checked the steps as per
[File upload along with other object in Jersey restful web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609569/file-upload-along-with-other-object-in-jersey-restful-web-service)

Glassfish Server:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEMessage.close()V
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderClientSide.getMimeParts(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:276)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readMultiPart(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderServerSide.readMultiPart(MultiPartReaderServerSide.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readFrom(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:183)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readFrom(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:93)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1085)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:852)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:786)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:233)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider$ValueFactory.getEntity(FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider$FormDataParamValueFactory.provide(FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider.java:282)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParamValueFactoryWithSource.provide(ParamValueFactoryWithSource.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:127)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$VoidOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:143)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:309)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:460)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:334)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Controller:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;

@Path("fu")
public class FUController {

    /** Logger */
    private static final BaseLogger LOGGER = BaseLogger.getLogger(FUController.class);

    /**
     * 
     * @param inputStream
     * @param fileDisposition
     * @param dpName
     * @return
     */
    @POST
    @Path("/")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public void upload(@FormDataParam("fu") InputStream inputStream,
            @FormDataParam("fu") FormDataContentDisposition fileDisposition, @FormDataParam("msg") String dpName) {

        byte[] zipByte = null;
        String fileName = null;
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream)) {

            byte[] fbytes = new byte[1024];
            int length = 0;
            while ((length = bis.read(fbytes)) > 0) {
                bos.write(fbytes, 0, length);
            }
            zipByte = bos.toByteArray();
            fileName = fileDisposition.getFileName();
            System.out.println("filename = " + fileName + "\t zipByte = " + zipByte.length);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Failure in file upload", e);
        }

        LOGGER.info("File {} is uploaded", fileName);
    }
}
```

ApplicationConfig:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;

public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<>();
        // final Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        resources.add(MultiPartFeature.class);
        return resources;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put("jersey.config.server.provider.classnames", "org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature");
        return props;
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jvnet.mimepull/mimepull -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.mimepull</groupId>
    <artifactId>mimepull</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
```

how does one say "which version of jersey am i using?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following dependency was missing in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
```

that fixed things.

i added some File I/O Control & Debug code too

```
@POST
@Path("/")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public void upload(@FormDataParam("fu") InputStream inputStream,
        @FormDataParam("fu") FormDataContentDisposition formDataContentDisposition) {

    String zipByte = null;
    String fileName = null;
    String fileType = null;
    long fileSize = 0;
    OutputStream out = null;
    File target = null;
    try {

        fileName = formDataContentDisposition.getFileName();
        fileType = formDataContentDisposition.getType();
        fileSize = formDataContentDisposition.getSize();
        target = new File("/home/research/" + fileName);
        out = new FileOutputStream(target);
        LOGGER.info("filePath = " + target + " fileSize = " + fileSize + " fileType = " + fileType);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        LOGGER.error("Current Path not Found");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream)) {

        byte[] fbytes = new byte[1024];
        int length = 0;
        while ((length = bis.read(fbytes)) > 0) {
            out.write(fbytes, 0, length);
        }
        zipByte = out.toString();
        LOGGER.info("zipByte = " + zipByte.length());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Failure in file upload", e);
    }
    LOGGER.info("File {} is uploaded at " + target.getAbsolutePath());
    try {
        LOGGER.info("File {} is uploaded at " + target.getCanonicalPath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Canonical Path not Found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Spent 5 days finding this!